# Globbing files with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, command-line-interface, glob

I'm writing a CLI that runs off nodejs and the basic usage scenario is that one would pass in a number of files, and/or folders, and/or glob patterns; eg:

```
my-cli file.foo file2.foo
my-cli folder/ folder2/
my-cli folder/**/*.foo folder2/**/*.foo
my-cli file.foo folder/ folder/**/*.foo
```

And so on. I'm wondering what's the most *efficient* way of handling whatever file/folder/glob style input? I'm using [Optimist](http://npmjs.org/package/optimist) to get the `argv._` (all the args) and this is my `coffeescript` (sorry) code handling the different variantions of the input:

```
_ = require 'lodash'
fs = require 'fs'
glob = require 'glob'

module.exports = (files) ->
  htmlFiles = []
  ext = 'html'
  files = _.flatten files

  _.forEach files, (file) ->
    fileExt = file.split('.').pop()

    if fileExt isnt ext
      if fs.lstatSync(file).isDirectory()
        file = if file.charAt(file.length - 1) isnt '/' then file + '/' else file
        htmlFiles.concat glob.sync file + '**/*.' + ext

    else
      htmlFiles.push file
```

I feel this is a bit messy and I'm hoping that there's a nice library somewhere in `npm` that I could use or make use of some other tricks?

Comment: I have, I'm actually using it in the example